# Bug unsubscribing from Ubuntu One Mobile

Tags: ubuntu-one

I have an Ubuntu One Mobile subscription, which I can see in my subscriptions page:

one.ubuntu.com/account/subscription/756082

I no longer need my Ubuntu One Mobile subscription, so click the link to cancel the Mobile service subscription:

one.ubuntu.com/account/cancel/756082/

Then confirm that request to cancel:

one.ubuntu.com/account/cancel/756082/confirm/

But the process ends there showing a "Something has gone wrong page", and my subscription remains active :(

The same problem occurred when I attempted the same a few weeks back, so not a temporary problem I'm thinking.

Any input gratefully received.

I would like to report this problem directly to the maintainer of this part of the Ubuntu site but cannot see how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for reporting this. I have found the issue and a fix is under way.

Meanwhile, I'm going to cancel your subscription manually. It will continue to work until it expires.

Answer (score 0):

Ask Ubuntu isn't usually the best place for bug reports.

The best way for you to report this problem is using [Ubuntu One's support form](https://one.ubuntu.com/support/contact/). I'm sure they will be very grateful if you send them a message.

Comment: For account related issues, we do prefer people to contact us via our support form. We monitor this forum as well but normally you don't want to supply account related details in the open. :)